# LuaBridge Indescriptive errors

Tags: c++, lua, compilation, luajit, luabridge

I use LuaJit and LuaBridge to compile lua code and execute it.
When the lua code throws an error, it's really hard to debug - I don't know what line it happened or what caused it.

This is an example:
`[string "1"]:0: bad argument #1 to 'info' (string expected, got table)`
in the code:

```
"function foo(bar)\n"
        "   logger:info(bar.moo);"
```

How do I translate `[string "1"]` to the matching code line?
Can I get a stacktrace?

The lua code is "compiled" with doing `string.dump` on the text code, and then loading it with `luaL_loadbuffer`.
Psuedo code that loads and calls the lua function:

```
int result = luaL_loadstring(L, script.c_str());
auto script_function = luabridge::LuaRef::fromStack(L);
auto string_module = luabridge::getGlobal(L, "string");
auto string_dump = string_module["dump"];
auto code = luabridge::LuaRef_cast<std::string>(string_dump(script_function, strip));
luaL_loadbuffer(L, code.data(), code.size(), std::to_string(current_id++).c_str());
lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, -1);

auto func_to_call = luabridge::getGlobal(L, "foo");
func_to_call(&bar);
```

Comment: How do you get the code into Lua?

Comment: I retrieve the function with getGlobal and call it

`auto func_to_call = luabridge::getGlobal(L, "foo");

func_to_call(&bar);`

Comment: But how do you load the code into Lua?

Comment: oh right, I use string.dump to "compile" the lua code into byte code (not exactly my code, missed it), and load it with `luaL_loadbuffer`

Comment: (1) How did you load the Lua source code? and (2) how do you call luaL_loadbuffer, and (3) why do I need to keep asking for related information?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really related.. I edited and added the code used (psuedo, can't send the exact snippets)

Comment: What is "strip"?

Answer (score 1):

`[string "1"]` comes from the chunk name you provided here: `std::to_string(current_id++).c_str()`

Since it doesn't start with @ it's treated as the string that was loaded, hence the `[string ""]` syntax. If you want the error message to treat it as a filename, put @ in front of the filename.

And I suspect that the reason the line number is 0 because you told Lua to delete the line numbers, by setting "strip" to true.